# Sum of Completion Times

Tags: arithmetic

I am trying to understand the solution of sum of completion times. I found the following stuff in the link:

[Prompt Scheduling for Selfish Agents](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.03244.pdf)
Paper says:

> Consider the case of a single queue, a selfish agent will simply join
>   the queue immediately upon arrival, there is no reason to delay. Thus,
>   jobs will be processed in first-in-first-out (FIFO) order. However,
>   this may be quite bad in terms of the sum of completion times. Imagine
>   a job with processing time L, arriving at time zero, followed by
>   sqrt(L) jobs of length 1, all of which arrive immediately after the
>   first. As the first job will only be done at time L, the sum of
>   completion times for these 1 +sqrt(L) jobs is about L^(3/2)

I can’t understand how this value of L^(3/2) is obtained.

Is it simply:

> L + L^(1/2)

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length-$L$ job obviously has a turnaround time (enqueue-to-done-processing) of $L$. The first length-$1$ job has a turnaround time of $L+1$, the second $L+2$ and so on, up to $L+\sqrt L$ for the last job. The aforementioned sum of completion times is
$$L+(L+1)+(L+2)+\dots+(L+\sqrt L)\sim L\sqrt L+\frac{\sqrt L(\sqrt L+1)}2\sim L^{3/2}$$