# Total Completion Time using Shortest Job First

Tags: arithmetic

I am trying to understand the solution of sum of completion times. I found the following stuff in the link:
[Prompt Scheduling for Selfish Agents](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.03244.pdf)

> Consider the case of a single queue, a selfish agent will simply join
>   the queue immediately upon arrival, there is no reason to delay. Thus,
>   jobs will be processed in first-in-first-out (FIFO) order. However,
>   this may be quite bad in terms of the sum of completion times. Imagine
>   a job with processing time L, arriving at time zero, followed by
>   sqrt(L) jobs of length 1, all of which arrive immediately after the
>   first. As the first job will only be done at time L, the sum of
>   completion times for these 1 +sqrt(L) jobs is about L^(3/2)

I am able to understand the completion time of the above through a solution on the.stackExchange ([Solution of Completion Times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3534782/sum-of-completion-times)). Now I want to understand the running time of the shortest job first:

The paper says following (i.e. text2)  immediately after the above text:

> Contrawise, if the sqrt (L) length one jobs were processed before
>   length L job, the sum of completion times would be about 2L. Obviously
>   it seems a good idea to delay longer good idea to delay longer jobs
>   and expedite shorter jobs.

I have tried following:

```
1 + 2 + 3 +………..+sqrt(L) + L
=(Sqrt(L) ( sqrt(L) + 1))/2 +L

=L/2 + sqr(L)/2 + L
```

I don't know how is it 2L as above in the paper text2.

Some body please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual sum of completion times is
$$1+2+\dots+\sqrt L+\sqrt L+L$$
$$\sim\frac{\sqrt L(\sqrt L+1)}2+\sqrt L+L$$
$$=\frac{L+\sqrt L+2\sqrt L+2L}2=\frac32(L+\sqrt L)$$
To say it is "about $2L$" is providing an upper bound on this expression.